# Replace values for each group

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I want to replace values in ['animal'] for each subid/group, based on a condition.

The values in animal column are numbers (0-3) and vary for each subid, so **a** where cond == 1 might look like [0,3] for one subid or [2,1] or [0,3] and the same goes for **b**.

```
for s in sids:
    a = df[(df['subid']==s)&(df['cond'] == 1)]['animal'].unique()
    b =  df[(df['subid']==s)&(df['cond'] == 0)]['animal'].unique()
    df["animal"].replace({a[0]: 0,a[1]:1,b[0]:2,b[1]:3})
```

The thing is I think the dataframe overwrites entirely each time and uses only the last iteration of the for loop instead of saving the appropriate values for each group.

I tried specifying the subid at the beginning like so,  `df[df['subid']==s["animal"].replace({a[0]:0,a[1]:1,b[0]:2,b[1]:3})` but it didn't work.

Any pointers are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you print out what your data looks like

Comment: i expect you want to do `df_new = df` so as not to overwrite the original.  If you can include the original dataframe, that would be most helpful.

Comment: @ifly6 Data would look like:
subid:1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,
animal:1,3,2,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,4,2,1
cond:0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1